# Convert pine script version 2 to version 4

Tags: pine-script

How to convert pine version 2 to version 4? I don't have even basic knowledge about pine. I tried this by watching pine script. But I don't understand version 4.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © imani45

//@version=2
study("PRS Supertrend", overlay = true)


//SUPER TREND INPUT

Factor1=input(3, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Factor2=input(2, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Factor3=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)

Pd1=input(7, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd2=input(14, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd3=input(21, minval=1,maxval = 100)


Up1=hl2-(Factor1*atr(Pd1))
Up2=hl2-(Factor2*atr(Pd2))
Up3=hl2-(Factor3*atr(Pd3))
Dn1=hl2+(Factor1*atr(Pd1))
Dn2=hl2+(Factor2*atr(Pd2))
Dn3=hl2+(Factor3*atr(Pd3))


TrendUp1=close[1]>TrendUp1[1]? max(Up1,TrendUp1[1]) : Up1
TrendUp2=close[1]>TrendUp2[1]? max(Up2,TrendUp2[1]) : Up2
TrendUp3=close[1]>TrendUp3[1]? max(Up3,TrendUp3[1]) : Up3

TrendDown1=close[1]<TrendDown1[1]? min(Dn1,TrendDown1[1]) : Dn1
TrendDown2=close[1]<TrendDown2[1]? min(Dn2,TrendDown2[1]) : Dn2
TrendDown3=close[1]<TrendDown3[1]? min(Dn3,TrendDown3[1]) : Dn3

Trend1 = close > TrendDown1[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp1[1]? -1: nz(Trend1[1],1)
Trend2 = close > TrendDown2[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp2[1]? -1: nz(Trend2[1],1)
Trend3 = close > TrendDown3[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp3[1]? -1: nz(Trend3[1],1)


Tsl1 = Trend1==1? TrendUp1: TrendDown1
Tsl2 = Trend2==1? TrendUp2: TrendDown2
Tsl3 = Trend3==1? TrendUp3: TrendDown3


linecolor1 = Trend1 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor2 = Trend2 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor3 = Trend3 == 1 ? green : red

plot(Tsl1, color = linecolor1 , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend1")
plot(Tsl2, color = linecolor2 , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend2")
plot(Tsl3, color = linecolor3 , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend3")



plotshape(cross(close,Tsl1) and close>Tsl1 , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
plotshape(cross(Tsl1,close) and close<Tsl1 , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

plotarrow(Trend1 == 1 and Trend1[1] == -1 ? Trend1 : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
plotarrow(Trend1 == -1 and Trend1[1] == 1 ? Trend1 : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
```

Comment: Did you try to convert it yourself?

Comment: Yeah I tried by seeing other pine script version 4. But I can't do it. That's why I asked here. 

Comment: I convert scripts all the time and in my honest opinion you should convert to v5 instead because they made everything more user friendly. As an example the max function in  your script is math.max instead

Comment: Hi I am completely new to pine script. I even don't know basics, the above script is copied from someone and made some adjustments based on my need. But I can't convert it into lastest versions. If you help me to covert it to any of version 4 or 5 should be very helpful. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference - if you just change the `//@version=2` to `//@version=5` and try to run the script, most of the changes needed will be written in the console.

Here is the code for version 5:

```
//@version=5
indicator("PRS Supertrend", overlay = true)


//SUPER TREND INPUT

Factor1=input.int(3, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Factor2=input.int(2, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Factor3=input.int(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)

Pd1=input.int(7, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd2=input.int(14, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd3=input.int(21, minval=1,maxval = 100)


Up1=hl2-(Factor1*ta.atr(Pd1))
Up2=hl2-(Factor2*ta.atr(Pd2))
Up3=hl2-(Factor3*ta.atr(Pd3))
Dn1=hl2+(Factor1*ta.atr(Pd1))
Dn2=hl2+(Factor2*ta.atr(Pd2))
Dn3=hl2+(Factor3*ta.atr(Pd3))


TrendUp1 = float(na)
TrendUp2 = float(na)
TrendUp3 = float(na)


TrendUp1 := close[1]>TrendUp1[1]? math.max(Up1,TrendUp1[1]) : Up1
TrendUp2 := close[1]>TrendUp2[1]? math.max(Up2,TrendUp2[1]) : Up2
TrendUp3 := close[1]>TrendUp3[1]? math.max(Up3,TrendUp3[1]) : Up3

TrendDown1 = float(na)
TrendDown2 = float(na)
TrendDown3 = float(na)

TrendDown1 := close[1]<TrendDown1[1]? math.min(Dn1,TrendDown1[1]) : Dn1
TrendDown2 := close[1]<TrendDown2[1]? math.min(Dn2,TrendDown2[1]) : Dn2
TrendDown3 := close[1]<TrendDown3[1]? math.min(Dn3,TrendDown3[1]) : Dn3

Trend1 = float(na)
Trend2 = float(na)
Trend3 = float(na)

Trend1 := close > TrendDown1[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp1[1]? -1: nz(Trend1[1],1)
Trend2 := close > TrendDown2[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp2[1]? -1: nz(Trend2[1],1)
Trend3 := close > TrendDown3[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp3[1]? -1: nz(Trend3[1],1)


Tsl1 = Trend1==1? TrendUp1: TrendDown1
Tsl2 = Trend2==1? TrendUp2: TrendDown2
Tsl3 = Trend3==1? TrendUp3: TrendDown3


linecolor1 = Trend1 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor2 = Trend2 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor3 = Trend3 == 1 ? color.green : color.red

plot(Tsl1, color = linecolor1 , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend1")
plot(Tsl2, color = linecolor2 , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend2")
plot(Tsl3, color = linecolor3 , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend3")



plotshape(ta.cross(close,Tsl1) and close>Tsl1 , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,color.green)
plotshape(ta.cross(Tsl1,close) and close<Tsl1 , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, color.red)

plotarrow(Trend1 == 1 and Trend1[1] == -1 ? Trend1 : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=color.new(color.lime, 0), maxheight=60, minheight=50)
plotarrow(Trend1 == -1 and Trend1[1] == 1 ? Trend1 : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=color.new(color.red, 0), maxheight=60, minheight=50)
```

[image]